# VS2010 RC - only 100 std::map elements in debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2010, stdmap

I have a small problem during debugging my App in VS 2010 RC when I want to see all the elements of std::map container.

When debugger reaches the breakpoint and I want to check the values of the map in element inspector (in 'Locals' windows and in pop-up windows after hovering the variable name with mouse as well) and I'm scrolling down the list of the elements it stops on the 100 element and I can't next elements. The map contains more than 200 elements (map's counter parameter shows this properly) but I can't view them all in the element inspector.

The problem appears even in the most simple `std::map<int, int>` filled with 200 int values.

Maybe this is a problem with settings, but I've tried many combinations of them and it still does not work. Maybe somebody have some ideas how to solve this.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I would guess that it's just a limitation of the debugger. They likely chose to have some upper limits so for **really** big data structures it doesn't just hang for what looks like forever.

Comment: For this particular case, could you not just debug the old fashioned way and print out the map contents to stdout or a file? It's only a few lines of code, and will probably only be a one-off job.

Comment: Report the issue with Microsoft (https://connect.microsoft.com/) if you feel it needs addressing.

Comment: @Poita_: I did so, but it is solved "for now", and I just wanted to fix it for the future

@Evan Teran, @Max: When I asked my friends about it, on VS 2008 everything worked properly, so maybe it's 2010 issue (I've checked my settings with theirs (those which are available) but they are the same), but I thought that such a problem should heave been notices in Beta version and isn't present in RC version, but maybe I'm wrong and should do as Max said...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The display of such information is directed by the autoexp.dat file (usually located in "Program Files*"\"Microsoft Visual Studio*"\Common7\Packages\Debugger).
It seems that Microsoft added a hard coded limitation of 100 elements to the #tree operator, in order to avoid freezing Visual Studio in case of loops in the tree.

Comment: On VS 2008, there is also a limit: the value string is limited to about 400 characters, finishing with ... to indicate that there are more values.

Answer (score 3):

With VS 2010 SP1 this limit was increased to a default value of 2000 entries.  This can also be modified by setting a registry key (all the standard warnings about modifying the registry apply here):

- for x86:
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\NativeDE\VisualizerMaxChildren
- for x64:
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\NativeDE\VisualizerMaxChildren

Scot Brennecke, Escalation Engineer
Microsoft VC++ Support