# is the MSVC++2010 debugger limited?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, limit

i'm trying to check what's in my set in the debugger,
i have 170 objects in it but i can only see 99 of them,
is the debugger limited?
he can show only 99 objects?
can i see all the objects?
thanks.

Comment: oh sorry, i use visual studio 2010.

Comment: In my test, MSVC++2010's debugger also displays only the 100 elements of a standard set.  I can't see how you'd get a complete list.

Comment: What's that? You got 99 objects but your instance ain't one </jayz>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[VS2010 RC - only 100 std::map elements in debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327316/vs2010-rc-only-100-stdmap-elements-in-debugger)

Answer (score 1):

May be that's why they have 4 Watch Windows (Debug/Windows/Watch).

Is [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/6b0cee18-8c1b-44ad-b82d-b8da1534fb34/) helpful?